# Do you need a dedicated server for source control?

Tags: server, version-control, perforce

A few schoolmates and I are using Unreal Engine 4 to develop a pretty large game. The one problem we have is that the game is constantly growing in size and is rapidly changing. We need a source control system, some researching indicates that Helix Core is the way to go however it is unclear whether I have to run a server off my own machine or spend money on a proper central server. I am completely in the dark about all things servers and would appreciate some help!

Thanks.

Comment: Perforce would like you to think so, but their marketing is rather misleading in this respect. Git can perfectly well be configured to use a centralized model, using Github or your own server, dedicated or on a workstation of one of your developers (as long as the others can connect to it, of course).

Answer (score 0):

p4d is not very resource-intensive and should be fine to run on your own machine for a project with only a few contributors.  It will also be easier IMO if you aren't familiar with server administration -- I've talked to a lot of UE developers who try to admin remote Linux servers following guides they've seen online and then are completely lost when it's time to debug something because they've never used a Linux command line.

The main constraint you're likely to hit is disk space -- game projects tend to have large generated assets, and anything under version control is necessarily going to be stored per-version on the server.  I'd probably solve this by getting a large external disk, putting the depot on that, and forgetting about it, but if that's not an option, you'll want to think about ways to limit the amount of data that goes into the server -- use filetype options for limited storage (using the `+Sn` option with `p4 typemap`), exclude generated files that can be rebuilt from what's already in source control (using `p4 protect` and/or stream definitions), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Git + LFS could be the right choice for you. GitLab gives you free private repo and supports LFS. Free tier should be enough for beginning, then if it will grow bigger, you will be able to extend it to your needs.

[A video tutorial about Git+Ue4 integration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXMTHrLWFKQ)

[.gitignore file you will need](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/UnrealEngine.gitignore)

[.gitattributes for LFS configuration](https://github.com/MOZGIII/ue4-gitignore/blob/master/.gitattributes)